# Como encontrar uma String a partir de Expressões Regulares

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2014

Tenho um campo no banco de dados SQL Server 2014 que armazena o endereço do cliente. O problema é que ficou tudo armazenado num único campo `varchar`.

Segue alguns exemplos reais:

> Rua Antonio José Nerchis, 81
>    Rua: Guaira/JD Pacera, 1201
>   Rua 321, N 168
>   R ALTAIR GAGLIARDI, 132
>   Rua Rio Grande do Sul, 243
>   Rua Duque de Caxias
>   R CAPELLEN, 58
>   ROD ACESSO PLINIO ARLINDO DE NEZ, 4303
>   R Anibal Gazaniga, 107
>   R D PEDRO I, 231
>   Rua Dep. Ivan Ferreira do Amaral, 440
>   R SANTA CATARINA, 711
>   Rua Santa Catarina, 411
>   Rua Augusto de Jesus, 77
>   Rua Marcondes Sobrinho, 40
>   rua Antonio Tonelli nº 755

Preciso mover isso para as 3 colunas:

- Tipo de logradouro (rua, avenida, vila...)
- O logradouro em si (nome da rua, avenida, vila...)
- Número do logradouro (número e demais complementos que podem ter sido colocados junto do logradouro)

Alguém sabe me dizer se tem como fazer isso via expressão regular? Se sim, como? Não entendo praticamente nada de expressões regulares.

Comment: você pode posta uma amostra dos seus dados, todos estão separados por , virgula  ?

Comment: Pode ser possível, dependendo se seus dados seguem algum tipo de padrão. Forneça mais alguns exemplo de dados para poder identificar algum padrão.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Padrão...ta difícil de achar, mas segue mais alguns exemplos... Vou colocar na questão mais exemplos.

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 adicionei exemplos reais na questão.

Comment: Se os inputs forem abertos para o usuário pode ser complicado definir uma expressão para todos os casos, pois o usuário pode preencher como desejar.

Comment: Não conseguir notar nada fora que o numero esta sempre no final, ainda assim como o @gmsantos comentou se tornaria muito problemático tentar tratar todos os casos. Sem falar que não da para saber se `R` é de rua ou rodovia. Seria mais util alterar o sistema e informar o cliente para que eles atualizem os dados.

Comment: Concordo com o @GuilhermeLautert. Essa seria a solução com melhor confiabilidade

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert entendi tua posição, aliás, fiquei na mesma situação quando tentei solucionar este problema... Infelizmente essa opção de atualizar os dados é inviável, visto que é um cadastro interno e que o responsável por isso teria que entrar em muitos cadastros (mais ou menos 1900 registros...). Se criarmos o seguinte padrão, sempre inicia com "Rua" e termina com o número, como ficaria a expressão regular?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ATENÇÃO**: Antes de executar os passos descritos nesta resposta, faça um backup da sua tabela no caso de algo dar errado.

Não acho que expressão regular resolva o seu problema, ao menos não facilmente.

Agora, imagine que você tenha esses endereços na coluna `endereco` de uma tabela chamada `tabela`.

Então, você primeiro adicionaria os campos necessários:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN logradouro varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN numero_logradouro varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN tipo_logradouro varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL;
```

O tamanho do campo `logradouro` deve ser o mesmo do campo `endereco`.

Daí, você só tem que popular esses campos. Vamos começar separando o tipo do logradouro do resto:

```
UPDATE tabela SET
    tipo_logradouro = 'Rua',
    logradouro = SUBSTRING(endereco, 3, 9999)
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTRING(endereco, 1, 2)) = 'R ';

UPDATE tabela SET
    tipo_logradouro = 'Rua',
    logradouro = SUBSTRING(endereco, 4, 9999)
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTRING(endereco, 1, 3)) = 'R. ';

UPDATE tabela SET
    tipo_logradouro = 'Rua',
    logradouro = SUBSTRING(endereco, 5, 9999)
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTRING(endereco, 1, 4)) = 'RUA ';

UPDATE tabela SET
    tipo_logradouro = 'Avenida',
    logradouro = SUBSTRING(endereco, 4, 9999)
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTRING(endereco, 1, 3)) = 'AV ';

UPDATE tabela SET
    tipo_logradouro = 'Avenida',
    logradouro = SUBSTRING(endereco, 5, 9999)
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTRING(endereco, 1, 4)) = 'AV. ';

UPDATE tabela SET
    tipo_logradouro = 'Avenida',
    logradouro = SUBSTRING(endereco, 9, 9999)
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTRING(endereco, 1, 8)) = 'AVENIDA ';
```

E então, você faz os mesmos passos para praça, vila, estrada, rodovia, alameda, etc.

Observe que 9999 é apenas um valor grande o suficiente para caber o endereço inteiro. Se o endereço for `varchar(123)`, então trocar o 9999 por 123 será o bastante.

Agora é a vez de separar o número. Primeiro normalizamos:

```
UPDATE tabela SET logradouro = REPLACE(logradouro, 'nº ', ', ');
UPDATE tabela SET logradouro = REPLACE(logradouro, 'nº', ', ');
UPDATE tabela SET logradouro = REPLACE(logradouro, 'Nº ', ', ');
UPDATE tabela SET logradouro = REPLACE(logradouro, 'Nº', ', ');
```

Depois, separamos o número após a última vírgula. Para achar a última, usamos a expressão `LEN(logradouro) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE(logradouro), ',')`:

```
UPDATE tabela SET
    numero_logradouro = TRIM(SUBSTRING(logradouro, LEN(logradouro) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE(logradouro), ',') + 1, 9999)),
    logradouro = TRIM(SUBSTRING(logradouro, 1, LEN(logradouro) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE(logradouro), ',') - 1));
WHERE CHARINDEX(logradouro, ',') >= 1;
```

Por fim, veja quais são os registros que sobraram ou deram errado por algum motivo. Torça para que sejam poucos:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE endereco IS NOT NULL
AND (logradouro IS NULL
    OR numero_logradouro IS NULL
    OR tipo_logradouro IS NULL
);
```

Quando ter certeza que está tudo certo e que todos os registros estão corretos:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela DROP COLUMN endereco;
```

**Problemas**: O que está aqui ainda não é capaz de lidar com o complemento. E se o complemento estiver depois do número, pode dar errado. Se estes casos forem poucos, dá para tratar manualmente. Se forem muitos, edite a pergunta colocando uns exemplos e eu tento adaptar aqui na resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Para sua amostra de dados você pode fazer, altere a tabela dinâmica para sua tabela real, crie os campos na sua tabela e tente fazer a alteração.

Você pode usar um `Begin tran` e caso esteja tudo certo `commit` ou `rollback`

```
   declare @Enderecos table
(
  Enderecos varchar(max),
  TipodeLogradouro varchar(200),
  Logradouro varchar(200),
  Numero varchar(200)
)

insert into @Enderecos(Enderecos) values 
('Rua Antonio José Nerchis, 81'),
('Rua: Guaira/JD Pacera, 1201'),
('Rua 321, N 168'),
('R ALTAIR GAGLIARDI, 132'),
('Rua Rio Grande do Sul, 243'),
('Rua Duque de Caxias'),
('R CAPELLEN, 58'),
('ROD ACESSO PLINIO ARLINDO DE NEZ, 4303'),
('R Anibal Gazaniga, 107'),
('R D PEDRO I, 231'),
('Rua Dep. Ivan Ferreira do Amaral, 440'),
('R SANTA CATARINA, 711'),
('Rua Santa Catarina, 411'),
('Rua Augusto de Jesus, 77'),
('Rua Marcondes Sobrinho, 40'),
('rua Antonio Tonelli nº 755 casa 2')

update @Enderecos
set TipodeLogradouro = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(Enderecos, charindex(' ', Enderecos) - 1),',' , ''),':' , ''),';' , ''),
Numero = 
case when  Enderecos  like '%º%' then substring(Enderecos, charindex('º', Enderecos) - 1, 100 )
        else 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
        (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
        (reverse(left(reverse(Enderecos), charindex(' ', reverse(Enderecos)) -1)        
        ) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1251_ci_as, 'z', ''), 'x', ''), 'w', ''), 'y', ''), 'v', ''), 'u', ''), 't', ''), 's', ''), 'r', ''), 'q', ''), 'p', '')
        , 'o', ''), 'n', ''), 'm', ''), 'l', ''), 'k', ''), 'j', ''), 'i', ''), 'h', '')
        , 'g', ''), 'f', ''), 'e', ''), 'd', ''), 'c', ''), 'b', ''), 'a', ''),',' , ''),':' , ''),';' , ''),' ',''),'º',''),'.',''),'/',''),'\','')
      end
from @Enderecos 

update @Enderecos
set Numero = REPLACE(Numero,'N?','Nº')
update @Enderecos

set Logradouro = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Enderecos,TipodeLogradouro,''),Numero,'')
,':' , ''),';' , ''),',',''),'Nº',''),'.',''),'\','')


select *  from @Enderecos
```

alterei para ter um dado  `('rua Antonio Tonelli nº 755 casa 2')` com complemento.

Comment: Seu código funcionou, mas devo confessar que me perdi na quantidade de replaces. kkkkk

Answer (score 4):

O problema de um campo aberto para inserção pelo usuário é que mesmo que ele parece obvie/padrão, não se pode confiar em seu conteúdo. O ideal seria atualizar o sistema e criar tabelas de endereço:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tb_pais(
    id SERIAL,
    pais VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_uf(
    id SERIAL,
    uf VARCHAR(100),
    sigla CHAR(2),
    id_pais INTEGER REFERENCES tb_pais(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_cidade(
    id SERIAL,
    cidade VARCHAR(100),
    id_uf INTEGER REFERENCES tb_uf(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_bairro(
    id SERIAL,
    bairro VARCHAR(100),
    id_cidade INTEGER REFERENCES tb_cidade(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_logradouro(
    id SERIAL,
    logradouro VARCHAR(100),
    id_bairro INTEGER REFERENCES tb_bairro(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_cep(
    id SERIAL,
    cep VARCHAR(100),
    id_logradouro INTEGER REFERENCES tb_logradouro(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_endereco(
    id_cliente INTEGER REFERENCES tb_cliente(id),
    id_pais INTEGER REFERENCES tb_pais(id),
    id_uf INTEGER REFERENCES tb_uf(id),
    id_cidade INTEGER REFERENCES tb_cidade(id),
    id_bairro INTEGER REFERENCES tb_bairro(id),
    id_logradouro INTEGER REFERENCES tb_logradouro(id),
    id_cep INTEGER REFERENCES tb_cep(id),
    numero INTEGER
);
```

Com isso você elimina nomes duplicados, podendo ainda desenvolver sistemas de busca.

Feito isso você pode partir para a atualização do conteúdo no banco, que consistiria em capturar o conteúdo atual e inserir em seu devido lugar.

Digamos que [como comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150254/como-encontrar-uma-string-a-partir-de-express%C3%B5es-regulares?noredirect=1#comment310313_150254) seu campo atual siga o padrão `Rua endereço numero`, poderia se criar uma REGEX `[^ ]+ (.+?) (\d+?)`. Assim o grupo 1 seria o logradouro e o grupo 2 o número, a parte inicial até o primeiro espaço sendo descartada, `Rua Almeida, 123`, ficaria `Almeida,` para o logradouro e `123` para o numero do endereço.

Após este passo concluído, se criaria um gerenciamento para atualizar os dados do logradouro, e em caso de duplicata remoção e substituição dos id duplicados.

Comment: Eu pensei em todo um sistema de manutenção desses dados, em PHP, se quiser mais detalhes avise, mas sim vai dar bastante trabalho.